# When using ping with ansible it returns `Cannot execute command-line and remote command.`

Tags: ansible, debian, bastion-host

I want ansible to use .ssh/config for all the ssh connection as we are using proxyJump using bastian servers. I have a very simple inventory file.

```
[apps]
app[998:999]
```

when running the following command

```
ansible all -i ansible.cfg -m ping -vvvv
```

I get the following output

```
<app999> (255, b'', b'OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /home/hamzaafridi/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: /home/hamzaafridi/.ssh/config line 47: Applying options for app???\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug2: resolve_addr: could not resolve name app999 as address: Name or service not known\r\ndebug3: resolve_canonicalize: attempting "app999" => "app999.vetdrive.io."\r\ndebug1: Canonicalized hostname "app999" => "app999.vetdrive.io"\r\ndebug1: Re-reading configuration after hostname canonicalisation\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /home/hamzaafridi/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: /home/hamzaafridi/.ssh/config line 51: Applying options for app???.vetdrive.io\r\ndebug1: /home/hamzaafridi/.ssh/config line 55: Applying options for *.vetdrive.io\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -vvv -W \'[%h]:%p\' bast.vetdrive.io\r\nCannot execute command-line and remote command.\r\n')
app999 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /home/hamzaafridi/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: /home/hamzaafridi/.ssh/config line 47: Applying options for app???\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug2: resolve_addr: could not resolve name app999 as address: Name or service not known\r\ndebug3: resolve_canonicalize: attempting \"app999\" => \"app999.vetdrive.io.\"\r\ndebug1: Canonicalized hostname \"app999\" => \"app999.vetdrive.io\"\r\ndebug1: Re-reading configuration after hostname canonicalisation\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /home/hamzaafridi/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: /home/hamzaafridi/.ssh/config line 51: Applying options for app???.vetdrive.io\r\ndebug1: /home/hamzaafridi/.ssh/config line 55: Applying options for *.vetdrive.io\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -vvv -W '[%h]:%p' bast.vetdrive.io\r\nCannot execute command-line and remote command.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I am not sure what I doing wrong. I can simply do ssh app999 to access the server and it's working perfectly fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with .ssh/config I had `RemoteCommand byob` which doesn't work with ansible.